# Download attachments with same name without overwriting in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

As per my requirement,i need to download a file from mail inbox into a specified directory,later after some time if same comes in , i need to save the same file into the same directory but with different name,here previous file should not be overridden means files must be saved in the same directory with same names(here i have one assumption,that , for example if my file is abc.txt, after modifications if i download the modified file it can be saved as abc(1).txt ). how can i resolve my issue? can anybody assist me to come out from this issue in JAVA. Below is my code but it is overwriting same file.

```
if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
  // this message may contain attachment
  Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
  for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {

      // save an attachment from a MimeBodyPart to a file
      String destFilePath = "F:/unprocessed/"+part.getFileName();
      InputStream input = part.getInputStream();
      BufferedInputStream in = null;
    in = new BufferedInputStream(input);

      FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

      int byteRead;

      while ((byteRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
      }

      System.out.println("FileOutPutStream is Being Closed");
      output.close();

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This should happen by default, you don't have to do anything special for it, as I think file system takes care of it. Try it first and then put questions here if you face problems doing that.

Comment: @VPK can you please check my above code ? it is overwriting files.

Comment: Check if the file already exists before writing it, and choose a different name if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before, you need to check the existing files. Here's one way of doing that:

```
public String getUniqueFileName(String input) {
    String base = "F:/unprocessed/";

    String filename = base+input;

    File file = new File(filename);
    int version = 0;
    while (file.exists()) {
        version++;
        String filenamebase = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        file = new File(filenamebase+"("+ version+")"+extension);
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Then change the assignment of destFilePath to a call this method:

```
String destFilePath = getUniqueFileName(part.getFileName());
```